# Bash command to convert IP addresses into their "reverse" form?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

When I run nslookup on an IP (These are all examples)

```
nslookup 192.168.1.123
```

Current output:

```
41.31.211.111
```

Desired output:

```
111.211.31.41
```

I have a script that works just seeing if there's a more efficient way or a built-in `nslookup` command.

Comment: Have a look at the answers to this similar question on U&L [How to read an IP address backwards?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132779/how-to-read-an-ip-address-backwards)

Comment: To see if another way is more efficient, it would help to see your current script.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
echo 411.311.211.111 | awk -F. '{print $4"."$3"." $2"."$1}'
```

Output:

```
111.211.311.411
```

or

```
echo 411.311.211.111 | awk -F. '{OFS="."; print $4,$3,$2,$1}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a native function.  Call it like `reverseip 12.34.56.78` to have it print `78.56.34.12`.  Call it like `reversed=$(reverseip 12.34.56.78)` to capture the output into a variable.

```
reverseip () {
    local IFS
    IFS=.
    set -- $1
    echo $4.$3.$2.$1
}
```

`set` with a string argument tokenizes this string into `$1`, `$2`, etc based on the current value of `IFS`. So we are breaking up the function's input argument `$1` into tokens, which now replace the original `$1`, `$2`, etc. Because `IFS` is a dot, the input value in the original `$1` gets split up on dots. The dash `--` is a safety measure to signal the end of options to `set`, in case the actual value of `$1` would start with a dash (without the `--` you would then get an "unknown option" error, or, worse, random or even insecure behavior).

Comment: It would be nice if the `set -- $1` had a brief explanation.

Comment: @ychaouche Thanks for the feedback; added an explanation.

Comment: awesome exaplanation, awesome solution awesome you.